# Run same select on multiple tables within BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm creating a cron job that will export BigQuery/Firebase events into my own database. The way I'm going to do this is first run a query once in the morning to grab all new tables and then run an update on them periodically throughout the day. I currently have the following query that works but in production is much larger than this (around 100+ unions).

```
with allTables as ( 
  SELECT
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app
  FROM `dataset1.*`  

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app
  FROM `dataset2.*`  
) 
SELECT
  app as target,
  0 as datapoint_value,
  UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', '20170417')) AS datapoint_time
FROM allTables
GROUP BY app
```

Obviously, this is quite inefficient due to the wildcard tables and many unions. What I'm looking for is a more efficient way to query the same exact data on many tables at once. The main issue is that I cannot just simply specify `app_events_20170103` because although one dataset might have that, another could not.

I'm looking for a solution that's both "cheap" and quick. Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!